# How do PACs build lists for door knockers?

Tags: united-states

I work for a PAC right now as a door knocker, but they never told me how they make lists. How does a PAC make a list in the United States?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the United States,voter registration records are public information. They can be acquired in bulk from the countie's voter registrar's office, or  [looked up on the internet](https://voterrecords.com).

The registration records include name, age, address and the party they registered with. Especially the latter is very useful information for door-knocking campaigns, because people are most likely to support the party they registered for.

These records might also get cross-referenced with data from other public or non-public databases. For example, people who already donated to this or a similar cause in the past are more likely to donate again. But there are also other information source which can be cross-referenced to make out the most promising targets.

Comment: Doesn't that mean they can be prosecuted for not using their home address?

Comment: @acoder who are "they" and prosecuted for what crime? Anyway, this doesn't seem to relate to this question and answer.

Comment: it was a curiosity of mine when someone used a business address as a home address for voting.